# How to label months on julian day x axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot (in ggplot2) where the x axis ranges from julian day 1-365. Is there any way to add month labels and tick marks to a julian day axis?

(i.e.,scale_x_date)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and code you've tried so far?

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Maybe convert your Julian days to dates. See `?lubridate::yday`

Answer (score 5):

You were on the right track with `scale_x_date()`, but your Julian days do need to be  formatted as Dates first.  The trick is selecting an origin that makes sense for your data, and then using `scale_x_date()` to format the labels:

```
library(ggplot2)

# make data
value <- rnorm(365, mean = 0, sd = 5)
jday <- 1:365 # represents your Julian days 1-365; assumes no leap years

# make data frame and add julian day
d <- data.frame(jday = jday, value = value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(d)

# plot with date labels on x axis    
ggplot(d, aes(x = as.Date(jday, origin = as.Date("2018-01-01")), y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b")
```

[image: jday_axisplot]

Comment: This is a lovely and elegant solution to a problem I often face. Thanks, @Von!

Comment: @Nova So glad it was helpful :) your profile is inspiring, thanks for the kind words